# How to export interfaces with Asp.Net Core Dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In MEF I could export generic interfaces with this code:

```
registration.ForTypesMatching(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Name) != null)
    .ExportInterfaces().SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared);
```

How can I configure services in Asp.Net Core to achieve the same, i.e. register service classes only by interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ASP.NET Core application you configure your services in the `Startup.cs` by extending the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method. The services parameter of a IServiceCollection instance lets you add your own services implementing an interface.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // setup of ASP.NET Services like MVC
    ...

    services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(objectImplementingMyInterface);
    services.AddTransient<IAnotherInterface, SomeAnotherInterfaceImplementer>();

}
```

If the basic features of the built in DI container (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) do not meet your requirements, then there are means to incorporate other DI container libraries, too. One example is Autofac (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html). The ASP.NET Team is currently working on changes that makes it easier for DI library maintainer to integrate into ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Integrating any container in ASP.NET Core is always easy, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core provides its own Inversion of Control container represented by IServiceProvider interface.
For basic usage and how to register your own classes check this page: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#.